# How do I load a FileResource into a byte array?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a file called `data.dat` that I would like to load into a `byte[]` in Vaadin. It is a data file that I need to load and then manipulate based on the user's input.

I tried:

```
String basepath = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
FileResource resource = new FileResource(new File(basepath + MY_DATA_FILE));
```

The problem is that I don't know how to manipulate the `resource` to extract the `byte[]`. I see [lots of information for how to put images and so on to the UI components](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/application.resources.html), [how to stream a user generated PDF](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.printing.html), and so on, but I can't seem to find any examples on how to load your own data file that you then manipulate within code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs of vaadin you have:

```
java.io.File    getSourceFile() 
      Gets the source file.
```

or

```
DownloadStream getStream() 
    Gets resource as stream.
```

And in `DownloadStream`:

```
java.io.InputStream getStream() 
      Gets downloadable stream.
```

So you can easily operate on `File` or `InputStream` to read the contents of a `FileResource`

For example in Java 8:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(resource.getSourceFile().getAbsolutePath()));
```

Comment: I missed the stream.stream as in IOUtils.toByteArray(resource.getStream().getStream()) if you use Apache Commons-IO.